# Jcrop setSelect wrong values

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I use jcrop in my application, I want to open the image with the selection `(x, y, w, h)` , when I give only the `x, width and height` it works, but when I add the value of `'y'` it it gives me no correct values

This is my code:

```
function initJcrop() {
                     $('#target').Jcrop({
                         aspectRatio: 3,  //If you want to keep aspectRatio
                          allowResize: true ,
                          boxWidth: 975,   //Maximum width you want for your bigger images
                          boxHeight: 325,  //Maximum Height for your bigger images
                          minSize: [900, 300],
                          <?php $image_crop =  json_decode($article->image_crop);?>
                          setSelect: [<?php echo $image_crop->x;?>, <?php echo $image_crop->y;?>, <?php echo $image_crop->w;?>, <?php echo $image_crop->h;?>],
                          allowSelect: false ,
                          onSelect: storeCoords ,
                          addClass: 'jcrop-centered',

                          onChange: storeCoords
                     },function()
                     {
    //                    alert('Now you see smaller preview of your bigger one.');
                     });
                    }



                function storeCoords(c) {
                    jQuery('#x').val(Math.round(c.x));
                    jQuery('#y').val(Math.round(c.y));
                    jQuery('#w').val(Math.round(c.w));
                    jQuery('#h').val(Math.round(c.h));
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the question was asked, but maybe comments in the following thread this will be helpful to others (like me) looking for an answer: https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/issues/150.